# My View is not getting Updated after Editing from Modal View SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, binding, observedobject, modal-view

I have View called TransferFlowView() and I have an ObservedObject.
`struct TransferFlowView: View { @ObservedObject var transferListVM =  TransferListViewModel() }`

In TransferListViewModel(), I have a function to Update viewModel.
`class TransferListViewModel: ObservableObject { init() { fetch } }`
And I call that update function in Modal View. So Whenever I click submit and dismiss Modal View, The
TransferFlowView() is not getting Updated.

I tried using binding property, used .onChange on TransferFlowView. It's not refreshing.
I want the view to be loaded, like first time, when it loads.

Comment: We'll need more detail or some code sample, what is "fetch" doing? Are you updating or filling a list of items in your viewModel?

Comment: try using `@StateObject var transferListVM =  TransferListViewModel()` in your `TransferFlowView`. Otherwise, show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use the View struct as the view model (as designed) and do the fetch in a .task storing the results in a state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableObject` relies on a synthesizes publisher `objectWillChange` to be triggered when there is a change, otherwise a view that observes this object through `@ObservedObject` wouldn't know when to refresh.

There are two ways to trigger that:

1. Manually by calling `objectWillChange.send()`

```swift
struct TransferFlowView: View {
    @StateObject var transferListVM = TransferListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text(transferListVM.update)
            
            Button(action: {
                transferListVM.fetch()
            }) {
                Text("Update")
            }
        }
    }
}

class TransferListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var update = UUID().uuidString
    
    init() {
        fetch()
    }
    
    func fetch() {
        update = UUID().uuidString
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

Here if you comment out `objectWillChange` you will see that the text doesn't change on the view.

2. Using `@Published` property.

If you add `@Published` to the property, it will automatically trigger `objectWillChange` when you assign a new value.
This code will have the same result:

```swift
class TransferListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var update = UUID().uuidString
    
    init() {
        fetch()
    }
    
    func fetch() {
        update = UUID().uuidString
    }
}
```

You also need to pay attention where you initilize a new instance of `TransferListViewModel`. In your current code you use `@ObservedObject` and it will be initializing a new instance of the view model every time you refresh the view. For that you have to pass the already initialized instance from outside.

Otherwise, you can use `@StateObject` which will call the initializer only once.